# Dismiss Modal View through popover didselcet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a splitView in my app.I have a presented a Modal on click of button from the splitview's detailview.In that modal I have opened popover which contains splitview's rootview controller(which contains tableview).

Now I want to dismiss that modal view on didSelect of popover's tableview.But it does not dismiss.
I have searched a lot for this and tried , but could not get any solution.

My Tried code is as follow:

```
//DetailView (Presented ModalView).m

    -(IBAction)popOverBtnPressed:(id)sender
    {
        LeftSideVCViewController *popUp=[[LeftSideVCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftSideVCViewController" bundle:nil];

        popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];
        popView.delegate =self;
        [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 700)];
        [popView presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(150,5,20,40) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

    }


    -(void)dismissModal
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }


   // LeftSideView.m

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        DetailView *d=[[DetailView alloc]init];   
       [d dismissModal];
    }
```

//  GridView.m

**Presenting DetailView from a view (GridView)**

```
-(IBAction)Grid_buttonPressed:(id)sender {

DetailView *rd=[[DetailView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
rd.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:rd animated:YES];
}
```

How to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: you are creating different instance of your ModelView at the time of presenting and dismissing that is why it is not dismissing it cause at the time of dismissing it its not the same instance of modelView you have presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing `DetailView *d=[[DetailView alloc]init]` u instantiate another instance of DetailView.
The way out in this situation would be  creating a delegate for LeftSideView

Somewhere above:

```
DetailView *instanceDV = [DetailView new];
LeftSideView *instanceLSV = [LeftSideView new];
instanceLSV.delegate = instanceDV;
```

And then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissModal)])
   [self.delegate dismissModal];

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But  how to create delegate of LeftSideView ?

Comment: to add a property in LeftSideView.h like this: @property (assign) NSObject *delegate;

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance of DetailView `d=[[DetailView alloc]init]`.Try to access the popover controller and dismiss it.

Comment: how can i access that popover in leftside view??

Comment: can you access your root controller i,e split view controller then try splitviewcontroller.detailcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to dismiss a UISplitViewController presented modally through its master popover. Not sure if that was the exact question but perhaps helpful to some.
From the master view itself (popover view):

```
//get the detail view
MyDetailViewClass *detailView = (MyDetailViewClass *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

//dismiss the master popover
[detailView.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

//dismiss the whole view
[detailView.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```